# Can I map MacOS cmd key to ctrl key on Kitty terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

As titled. Better yet if I could just map the right cmd key.

Many thanks!

Comment: specifically I mean kitty the GPU-rendered terminal:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875047/how-does-software-activation-work

not kiTTy

Comment: Welcome! This should be asked on SuperUser (or apple.stackexchange.com), not Stack Overflow (it's not programming-related).

Comment: While @DavidMakogon is right; I'll try help anyways.
To the questioner: What is it you're actually trying to achieve? Like, what's the use-case?

Comment: @JulianKirsch - This isn't a matter of wanting to help or not. This question will, in all likelihood, be closed and removed, along with any answers added (which doesn't seem fair to the OP, nor to you if you put in effort here, on the wrong site). This question (while needing more detail) fits *far better* on the sites I mentioned. Even on those sites, though, this question is still fairly broad and open-ended. Best to have the OP post to the appropriate place.